# ImportError: cannot import name pyqtSignal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qtpy

Background on the question: This is a previous PyQt project I am working on and trying to start the GUI. I have set an Anaconda Environment with Python 2.7 and used PyQt4. The Error is :-

`File "gui/gui.py", line 26, in <module>
        from qtpy.QtCore import (Qt, QFileSystemWatcher, QSettings, pyqtSignal)
    ImportError: cannot import name pyqtSignal`

Code :-

```
enter #import qt
from qtpy import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, PYQT4 #changed from PYQT5
from qtpy.QtCore import (Qt, QFileSystemWatcher, QSettings, pyqtSignal)
```

Even after trying to setup the environment and other aspects to the best of my ability, I am unable to pinpoint why this error still pops up.Tried on Mac, it errors out similarly even on Ubuntu. Does anyone have an idea how  to tackle this?

Comment: Please post your error message as text rather than as image, so it is easier to find it by search engines. Also, please show the relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using `qtpy` rather than `PyQt4` directly. According to [Don't delete QtCore.{pyqtSignal,pyqtSlot,pyqtProperty} · Issue #76 · spyder-ide/qtpy · GitHub](https://github.com/spyder-ide/qtpy/issues/76), they deliberately ditched `PyQt`-specific names like `pyqtSignal` and instead rename them upon import to generic names like `Signal` for uniformity. They comment that these names follow `Qt5`'s naming scheme.

So you should just

```
from qtpy.QtCore import Qt, QFileSystemWatcher, QSettings, Signal
```

and rename all `pyqtSignal` to `Signal` elsewhere in your code.